# How to set environment variable for C# debugging

Tags: c#, debugging, dll, environment-variables, path-variables

I'm trying to load managed and native dll into my C# application. I want to set the PATH environment variable, so the application can find the dlls to be loaded. In C++ that's easy, but how can I do that in a C# project? (By the way I'm using VS2012, .NET, WPF)

Comment: Note that if you use SetEnvironmentVariable() (as correctly answered by squillman below), only the process that calls SetEnvironmentVariable() and any processes that the calling process itself launches will be able to see that environment variable.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use [**Environment.SetEnvironmentVariable()**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/z46c489x.aspx).

```
string currentPath = Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("path");
Environment.SetEnvironmentVariable("path",currentPath + ";c:\path_to_libraries");
```

Keep in mind that this will only be in scope for the current process.  If you want to set a persistent environment variable (user or machine scope) use the `Environment.SetEnvironmentVariable(string, string, EnvironmentVariableTarget)` overload.  [**See here**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/96xafkes.aspx) for that reference.

Comment: I only need it for debugging, not at runtime. Can you do it through the project settings?

Comment: You could fake it. Check out the Debug tab in your project's settings. There's a "Start Action" setting, where you can select "start external program". I think you can specify a batch file there. In that batch file, you can set the PATH appropriately, and then run your program from the /debug output folder. (It'll probably be fiddly to work out the exact relative paths to use, both in the settings and in the batch file itself. Keep fiddling until it works. ;)

Comment: You could also set a reference path in properties of the project that is referencing the files.  That also carries over beyond debugging though, I believe...

Answer (score 2):

Be careful with this thing.  I would explicitly set the target e.g.
    System.Environment.SetEnvironmentVariable("windir", System.Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("SystemRoot"), EnvironmentVariableTarget.User);

When I did not set the target, very odd things happened to my Windows session requiring me to either logoff and login or even reboot.  So unless this change is really to be at the machine or process level, do not assume happy results with the default